# Why doesn't this CSS limit displayed container height?

Tags: css, html, browser, cross-browser

I have a CSS div that is supposed to have a maximum height. Its CSS has:

```
div#feed
    {
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: right;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    }
```

When entries are added to the div, it keeps growing until it is cut off by the bottom of the screen (and still keeps growing). This behavior is consistent across Chrome, Firefox, IE8, and IE9.

Is there a good cross-browser way to do what I am attempting in the CSS above?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the code for the parent element?  Percentage heights only work if the parent element has a height defined.  Otherwise I'm pretty sure it defaults to `auto`

Comment: I think that was the problem. When I replaced percentage heights with absolute calculated pixel values, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a height in percentage will only work on elements whose parent has a specified height. So if the parent has a calculated height it will work, however if the height is auto, it will not.

If you want % based heights to work, you need to specify a height for each element all the way up the DOM giving body 100% height.

If, however, you can give the parent a fixed height, well, problem solved.